# trying to show a variable in my layout

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

i have a simple question

where is my code wrong ?

in index controller and index action

i put

```
$this->view->username="user1";
```

and when i try in my layout i use

```
echo $this->username;
```

i got fllowing error or null value

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\test\application\layouts\layout.phtml on line 115

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `echo $this->view->username`?

Answer (score 0):

Your layout, where you are trying to echo your variable, is not your [view](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.scripts.html).

Essentially, it can't be. Let me explain: Your layout is a *global*, well, layout. Something that's specific for IndexController's **indexAction()** is (/ should be) logically unavailable in the global layout, since your layout will not have this variable if you end up calling, say, FooController's **barAction()**.

Your view would be at views/scripts/index/index.phtml - that's where you can use `<?php echo $this->username; ?>`

I haven't worked with variables in layouts yet, but this is what I'm gleaning from [the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.quickstart.html): If you want your layout to show a variable, try using `$this->_helper->layout->username = "user1"` in your action, that should let you use `echo $this->layout()->username` in the layout.

Be careful, though, if you do use layout variables, you also have to set them in each action. If you just want your **indexAction()** to show the username, you should try putting your echo into your view.

Comment: Which part does not work? Using index.phtml, or using layout variables?